# Como Fazer um Balão de Ajuda em WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação WPF, e nela, preciso que cada Label tenha um Balão Informativo, como exemplo, Nome* (nome completo);
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Gostaria de fazer em WPF puro, mas caso não dê, há alguma forma simples de fazer?

Comment: Não seria a propriedade ToolTip? https://www.wpftutorial.net/ToolTip.html

Comment: @L.Falousk poste uma resposta com o exemplo da implementação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo retirado do site já informado:

```
<Button ToolTip="Saves the current document"
        ToolTipService.ShowDuration="20"
        Content="Save">
</Button>
```

Acrescentando as propriedades de Tooltip, você já consegue exibir uma mensagem quando mouse passa encima.

Comment: Tipo, se eu selecionar o textbox ou cmb, queria que esta mensagem aparecesse...

Comment: Ok, vou alterar aqui.